# Retrieving auto increment value in php 5

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to retrieve the auto increment value from database. Now I am using this code it works good in my old php version but not working in php 5.

```
$result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$lastId = mysql_query($result, 0, 0);
$_SESSION['no'] = $lastId;
```

Comment: what is exact version of PHP & MySQL ?

Comment: might wanne stop using mysql_* functions..

Comment: What is your second query supposed to do?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: echo"$_SESSION[no]" I'm using this in another form

Comment: if you need last id you can do  by
select id order by id desc limit 1

Comment: Can you please explain in answers not in comment.

Comment: @apokryfos I would upvote your comment if you used this url instead: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown If the big red warning in the official PHP manual doesn't convince OP to switch to MySQLi what chance do I have?

Comment: @apokryfos haha well said. You know, this kind of user tends to automatically visually avoid that kind of warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function : mysqli_insert_id($con);
Note: $con is db connection.
Also refer the following link:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_insert_id.asp

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```